# How to make my Netbeans Java rest Client access Post method?

Tags: java, rest, post, netbeans, client

I have netbean Rest Web service project with several method as follow:

```
@Path("restws")
```

public class RestWs {

```
@Context
private UriInfo context;

public RestWs() {
}


@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String getJson() {
    return ("{\"pesan\":\"hello\"}");
}


@PUT
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String putJson(String content) {
    return("Content yang didapat : "+content);
}

@Path("/mahasiswaData/{id}")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String getMahasiswaByID(@PathParam("id")String nim)
{
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("id", nim);
    jo.put("nama", "Budi");
    return(jo.toJSONString());
}

@Path("/mahasiswaData/{id}")
@POST
@Consumes("text/plain")
@Produces("application/json")
public String postMahasiswaByID(@PathParam("id")String nim, String data)
{
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("id", nim);
    jo.put("nama", "Budi");
    jo.put("message", data);
    return(jo.toJSONString());
}

@Path("/mahasiswaQuery")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String getMahasiswaQuery(@QueryParam("nim")String nim, @QueryParam("nama") String nama)
{
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("nim", nim);
    jo.put("nama", nama);
    jo.put("method", "GET");
    return(jo.toJSONString());
}

@Path("/mahasiswaQuery")
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
public String postMahasiswaQuery(@QueryParam("nim")String nim, @QueryParam("nama") String nama)
{
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("nim", nim);
    jo.put("nama", nama);
    jo.put("method", "Post");
    return(jo.toJSONString());
}
```

}

then i make new project and add rest web service client. Automatically netbeans made me a new Class:

```
public class NewJerseyClient {
private WebTarget webTarget;
private Client client;
private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/PTIRestServer/webresources";

public NewJerseyClient() {
    client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
    webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("restws");
}

public String putJson(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), String.class);
}

public String getMahasiswaByID(String id) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("mahasiswaData/{0}", new Object[]{id}));
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
}

public String postMahasiswaQuery() throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.path("mahasiswaQuery").request().post(null, String.class);
}

public String getMahasiswaQuery(String nim, String nama) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    if (nim != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("nim", nim);
    }
    if (nama != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("nama", nama);
    }
    resource = resource.path("mahasiswaQuery");
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
}

public String postMahasiswaByID(Object requestEntity, String id) throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("mahasiswaData/{0}", new Object[]{id})).request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN), String.class);
}

public String getJson() throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
}

public void close() {
    client.close();
}
```

}

i can access all the get Method easily by using something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new NewJerseyClient().getMahasiswaQuery("23", "John"));
}
```

but when i try to access post/put method using this code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewJerseyClient c = new NewJerseyClient();
    System.out.println(c.putJson("{\"name\":\"john\"}"));
    System.out.println(c.postMahasiswaQuery());
    System.out.println(c.postMahasiswaByID("plain text", "1"));
}
```

all of the method call give me an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotAcceptableException: HTTP 406 Not Acceptable
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:898)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:749)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:88)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:650)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:421)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:646)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:402)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:305)
at client.NewJerseyClient.postMahasiswaByID(NewJerseyClient.java:68)
at client.NewJerseyClient.main(NewJerseyClient.java:84)
```

can anyone help me? how to access method put/post? or anyone has a sample code how to access those method?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Rest service code looks good. however the client code generations in Netbeans has an issue i have filed a [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258639) in netbeans.

To make your client code success. Please change the **putJson** request content type from *javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON* to *javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN*

```
 public String putJson(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
        return webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), String.class);
    }
```

Similarly for **postMahasiswaByID** method change the request content-type *javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN* to *javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON*

```
        public String postMahasiswaByID(Object requestEntity, String id) throws ClientErrorException {
        return webTarget.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("mahasiswaData/{0}", new Object[]{id}))
                .request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN), String.class);
    }
```

Please let me know if it works.

Thanks
vidhya

Comment: it's working!! thank you very much.. but how about

public String postMahasiswaQuery() throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.path("mahasiswaQuery").request().post(null, String.class);
}

the post method require Entity<t>, how can i made that object?

Comment: I am glad it works for you. And postMahasiswaQuery is working for me fina. Could you please update your questions with full example code and exception.